# How to call REST service using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, rest

Using the code I found from one of the StackOverflow postings, I'm trying to call a REST service GET method. However, when the code runs it is not putting the GET format correctly in the URL.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
    function UserAction(json)
    {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
            {
                alert(this.responseText);
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/isJsonValid/json", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        xhttp.send(json);
    }

</script>

<form>
    <button type="submit" onclick="UserAction(json)">Check if JSON Valid</button>
    <label for="json">JSON:</label>
    <input type="text" id="json" name="json"><br><br>
</form>

</html>
```

The expected format of this GET REST service would be:

http://localhost:8080/isJsonValid/json

(where json in the line above is the actual JSON sent as a parameter.)

Yet, what is shown in the URL line includes the project, directory and the URL has the ?name=value syntax.

Since the GET doesn't match the simple **http://localhost:8080/isJsonValid/json** format, I get a 404 error.

I realize there's something obvious I'm missing.

Thanks to all for suggestions.

Comment: Where does your `onclick` call to `UserAction(json)` get its value for `json`? By the way, you're missing a `<html>` tag near the beginning.

Comment: `UserAction(..)` on `onclick` handler should receive the json input value. Right now it recieves nothing, json is undefined. Furthermore the action does not return something if this is the intent

Comment: Do mean you want your json text to be part of the path, eg `/isJsonValid/{"key":"value"...}`? If so then you would need to use string concatenation to get that type of url

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send data you need to either send it as a query param or as the body. If you want to send it as a body need to use POST type. Below is the example of POST type.

```js
// Create a request variable and assign a new XMLHttpRequest object to it.
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

// Open a new connection, using the GET request on the URL endpoint
request.open('GET', 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films', true)

request.onload = function() {
 // Begin accessing JSON data here
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response)

  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    data.forEach(movie => {
      console.log(movie.title)
    })
  } else {
    console.log('error')
  }
}

// Send request
request.send()
```

For post Request. As I don't have any API with me I have used get API URL.

```js
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log(this.responseText)
         if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
             alert(this.responseText);
         }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhttp.send("Your JSON Data Here");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the great input and help!

The best solution for me was to just use, as suggested, a POST. The GET was always putting the "?" in the URL even if I concatenated it, That "?" isn't how the REST service interprets the GET parameters so it wouldn't work that way. In the REST framework I'm using, GET parameters are just concatenated with one or more "/" as separators in the URL.

Appreciate all the terrific help here on SO. :)

Comment: The real problem is that xmlHTTPRequest attaches its payload in a standard way for GET, and that is to use ?param=value syntax.  So, xmlhttp.send(json) is where that is taking place.  If you need a custom url format you would have to build that url string yourself out of the base url and the json parameter, and not pass the json parameter to the send method.